# Image grid layout not aligned with overflow y and x

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, grid-layout

I'm studying frontend and I found an interesting website layout, but I'm don't have any idea to do that, I haven't had a solid experience with frontend.

Someone has any idea to make something like that: https://dexternavy.com?

I would like to do an image grid, with images with different sizes and not aligned which other.

There's a plugin to make that? I prefer make with pure html, CSS and js to improve my skills.

Comment: Can you upload an image to your question that shows the site layout? Some people may not be able or willing to visit unknown websites.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a plugin to do that.

But you ask mainly "how to do that with pure HTML, CSS and JS".

So, if your main question is **"How to make an 'anarchic' layout without row / column rules"**, your best bet is the absolute positioning with CSS :)